# ios7 - storyboard - cannot set a navigation bar in my view controllers

Tags: ios7, xcode-storyboard

I have 2 view controllers ( AuthLogin View Controller and TabBar View Controller) and I am trying to set the navigation bar..
I added a navigation bar into my storyboard , but it does not appear ( not visible) in both view controllers.. I guess I am missing some param in the storyboard set up ...

I have  [image: storyboard-1]

but I should get  [image: storyboard-2 , note the visible navigation area at the top]

Comment: Your problem is that the navigation bar doesn't appear in the storyboard? or that when you run the project, they don't show the navigation bar in the app?

Comment: it doesn't appear at the top of  the 2 view controllers...  ( first picture => my project , 2nd picture => the tutorial )

Answer (score 0):

solved ... I need to set Top Bar: Opaque Navigation Bar" in the Simulated Metrics panel of each view ( using XCode 6...  I'll check if it's the same w XCode 5)

[image: make Navigation Top Bar visible in storyboard views]